# DocumentDb order By returning an error

Tags: sql-order-by, azure-cosmosdb

I am using documentDB for my database storage, and today I tried to write a query with order by clause, and the query is something like this

```
select * from root r where r.gender = 'Male'  ORDER BY r.age
```

it is returning an error,

```
{"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Order-by index path has a precision that might result in partially ordered results. To proceed with query execution, specify the enable low precision order by option in the request.\"]}\r\nActivityId: 73dc7fda-659e-4580-b000-2ca5124a44e6, Request URI: /apps/64ca7410-c445-4884-a8bb-32f6a60a6ca2/services/3dd6c9e7-3138-4968-b8e6-be51b4d9748e/partitions/30c57c8f-3494-419b-9f45-ec50582bffd9/replicas/130802821685931221p"}
```

However, the query without order by clause is executing fine and resulting correctly,

anything wrong with my query?

Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as per the error we are getting that the age column may be of type float or  double it is saying index path has a precision, so make it round in your order by clause

Comment: May be issue is not with dataType, when I try to give the order by name also same error occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify your indexing policy to use Maximum precision (-1) in order to execute Order By. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-orderby/#configure-an-indexing-policy-for-order-by

Comment: Can I modify indexing policy for already existed collections? or need to create new collection with this indexing policy? I have more than 20k records in each collection. and I don't want to lose the data.

Comment: This is not currently supported. You can watch changes for the feature availability here: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/8749198-dynamic-indexing-policies

Answer (score 2):

To add to the above answer, re-indexing collections while online is now possible

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-your-documentdb-indexing-policies-online/